# Align sentence with image in a table, without going off the margins (text multilignes)?

Tags: tables, align, margins, paragraphs

I have a problem with a table that I want to create, the sentences cannot be aligned automatically so I have to write \ everytime to change lines. I am sure there's an efficient way to do this.

```
        \documentclass[10.5pt, twoside, a4paper]{article}

           \usepackage{lipsum}
             
              \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}                   % Bilder
\usepackage{multicol}                   % Tabellen
\usepackage{lscape}                     % Querformat
\usepackage{geometry}                   % Seitenränder
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                   % Kopfzeile
\usepackage{lastpage} 
\usepackage{lipsum}                     % Dummy Text
\usepackage{enumitem}
\geometry{
        a4paper,
        top     =25mm,
        left    =25mm,
        right   =25mm,
        bottom  =20mm,
        headsep =5mm,
        footskip=12mm}



       \begin{table}[h!]\begin{tabular}{ m{0.5\linewidth} m{0.5\linewidth} }
                                            
      \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Images/Images - 09/01 - schéma armature long et precon .pdf} & 
       \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Les armatures transversales (en couleur), \\ ne permettent pas à respecter cette exigence. \\ Vérification pas remplie \redcross. \\ Les armatures comprimées (nappe supérieure) \\ sont augmentée à \phi 26 , s = 150 mm \end{tabular} 
                                               
       \end{tabular}
       \end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `minipage` instead.

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  Les armatures transversales (en couleur), ne permettent pas à
  respecter cette exigence. Vérification pas remplie.
  Les armatures comprimées (nappe supérieure) sont augmentée à
  $\phi=26$, $s = \qty{150}{mm}$.
\end{minipage}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that there is no `10.5pt` option, just `10pt` (default), `11pt` or `12pt`. Also `[h!]` is a good way to have float positioning problems.

Adjust the relative dimensions to suit your taste or need.

[image]

For alignment at the vertical centers, use a `tabular` around the image and remove `[b]` from the `minipage`.

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}% for vertical centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
  Les armatures transversales (en couleur), ne permettent pas à 
  respecter cette exigence. Vérification pas remplie.
  Les armatures comprimées (nappe supérieure) sont augmentée à 
  $\phi=26$, $s = \qty{150}{mm}$.
\end{minipage}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when i use a mini page i lose the verticale alignement between the image and the text. Is there a way to align them vertically ?

Comment: @YafietYohannes Do you want them aligned at the vertical center? See edit. Personally, I'd prefer bottom alignment, though.

Answer (score 0):

A wee bit change your MWEČ

- to preamble added `\usepackage[french]{babel}` and `\usepackage{siunitx}`
- in the second column removed nested table
- for column type is used `b` defined in the `array` package
- for font size is used default size at `a<rticloe` document class: 10pt

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
   \begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{@{} b{0.5\linewidth} b{0.5\linewidth} }
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    &   Les armatures transversales (en couleur), ne permettent pas à respecter cette exigence. Vérification pas remplie. Les armatures comprimées (nappe supérieure) sont augmentée à $\phi=26$, $s = \qty{150}{mm}$.
\end{tabular}
   \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]